# N queens Algorithm bug and how to print all solutions

Tags: java, algorithm, n-queens

Working on the a N queens problem (non-recursively and with a stack) and have two fairly specific questions:

My "notSafe" method, which checks if there are queens in the same row/column and diagonals as another queens isn't really working. I can't spot the logical mistakes and it could be due to another method "finish", which might not be backtracking correctly.

Also, a secondary question: Any thoughts on how to print out all solutions? Maybe a few hints to get me started.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Test1 {

static Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
static int topRow = 0;
static int currentRow = 0;
static int row = 0;
static int n = 8;


public static void main(String args[]) {

    finish(n);

}

public static void finish(int n) {
    placeQueen();
    placeQueen();

    boolean success = false;
    while (success != true) {

        if (notSafe() == true && s.empty() == false) {
            int c = 1;

            do {

                if (c <= n) {
                    s.pop();
                    row--;
                    c++;
                    s.push(c);
                    row++;
                } else if (c <= n && s.size() == 0) {
                    c++;
                    s.push(c);
                    row++;

                } else {
                    c = 1;
                    s.pop();

                }

            } while (notSafe() == true);

        } else if (s.size() == n && notSafe() == false) {
            display();
            break;
        } else {
            placeQueen();

        }

    }
}

public static boolean notSafe() {
    boolean status = false;
    int top = s.size()-1;

    topRow = row;
    int temp = row;
    currentRow = temp - 1;

    if (s.size() > 1) {

        for (int m = top; m >= 1; m--) {
            int x = (Integer) s.get(top);
            int y = (Integer) s.get(m - 1);
            if ((x == y) || x - y == currentRow || x + y == currentRow) {

                status = true;

            }
        }
    }

    return status;
}

public static void placeQueen() {

    s.push(1);
    row++;

}
//======Display=======//
public static void display() {
    int z = 0;
    while (z != s.size()) {

        int x = (Integer) s.pop();
        for (int y = 1; y <= n; y++) {

            if (x != (y)) {
                System.out.print("-");

            } else
                System.out.print("q");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe I'm the only one who isn't familiar with the N queens problem - could you help me out and add a link to the problem statement in your question?

Comment: @AndyTurner https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle

Comment: You don't have a `queensIsSafe` method. Do you mean `notSafe`?

Comment: Yes, the method I am referring to is notSafe.

Comment: @AndyTurner Hover your mouse over the tag `n-queens` at the bottom of the question, or [ask wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle).

Comment: Get rid of "not safe" in any case. Double negation is a typical source for mistakes. Replace it by "safe".

Answer (score 0):

A few issues to point out here:

- You seem to be placing two queens in row 1 in the first 2 columns. That will make the solution illegal (and assumes n > 1)
- You don't need to keep testing the queens you've already placed: just check if the row you are about to use for the next column is in the same row as any previous queens (change the method to accept a row to test).

If you follow those pieces of advice then you could simplify to:

```
private boolean rowIsSafe(int testRow) {
    for (int col = 0; col < stack.size(); col++) {
       if (stack.get(col) == testRow)
           return false;
       if (Maths.abs(testRow - stack.get(col)) == stack.size() - col)
           return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or, in Java 8:

```
IntStream.range(0, stack.size()).noneMatch(col -> stack.get(col) == testRow
    || Maths.abs(testRow - stack.get(col)) == stack.size() - col)
```

Printing out all solutions just means that you don't stop (i.e. `break`) once you hit a solution: print it, pop it and keep going.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm trying to wrap my head around what you're saying: So I don't have to keep testing the pieces I've placed? What about the diagonals?

Comment: You only need to test the new piece you're adding. But I did forget diagonals! Will add that to the test.

Comment: Last question : when passing rowIsSafe an int, is that the value of the stack currently? As in, would the stack have to be accessed and modified in a loop, checked by the rowIsSafe method, and the pushed when a correct solution is found?

Comment: Yes that's correct. You check `rowIsSafe` before pushing the row onto the stack.